# How do I print only the last value in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

For the below code, I only want to print the last approximation for the squareroot function, instead of printing out every approximation.

```
def square(x):
    guess = int(x/2)
    for i in range(1,10):
        nextguess = (guess + x/guess)/2
        guess=nextguess
        print(nextguess)
```

Comment: Why don't you print `guess` outside of the loop? That should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just de-denting your `print()` will work:

```
def square(x):
    guess = int(x/2)
    for i in range(1,10):
        nextguess = (guess + x/guess)/2
        guess=nextguess
    print(nextguess)
```

After the loop, `nextguess` still has the value form the last cycle. 
In Python, a loop does not create a new scope. So, everything you create or change in the loop is still available after the loop.

Comment: I'd rather `print(guess)`, it has the same value but it's guaranteed to be defined.

Comment: Because `for i in range(1,10):` is hardwired, `nextguss`will be define here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a list, for example, `List1` is the List name:

`List1 = ["praneeth","Veeru","Avinash","Harsha","Avinash"]`.

If you would like to print `Avinash` which is the last element of the list, you can use `List1[-1]` which returns the last element of the list.

Answer (score -2):

You can try doing it with a while loop

```
def square(x):
    guess = int(x/2)
    i = 1
    while (i < 10):
        nextguess = (guess + x/guess)/2
        guess=nextguess
        i = i + 1
    print(nextguess)
```