# Getting the last number from a FOR loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):

    count = 1
    for i in range(count,(maxN*count)+1):
        print(minN*count)
        count = count + 1
```

And if I call it like so: LCM(5,7) its gonna give me the numbers:

```
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
```

How could I make the program output (instead of all the numbers) just the last one, in this example: `35`

I tried looking it up in the other topics but none were of any help.

Comment: Could you add code of your previous attempts at this?

Comment: `if i==(maxN*count):print((maxN*count))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print only the last value in a for loop (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186574/how-do-i-print-only-the-last-value-in-a-for-loop-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `print` statement outside the for loop?

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    count = 1
    for i in range(count,(maxN*count)):
        count = count + 1
    print(minN*count)
```

---

```
LCM(5,7)
# 35
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify your LCM method:

```
def LCM(minN, maxN):
    print(minN * maxN)

LCM(5,7)
```

output:

```
35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **list**:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):

    count = 1
    results = []
    for i in range(count,(maxN*count)+1):
        results.append(minN*count)
        count = count + 1
    print(results[-1]) # print the last elements of the list.
```

So, when You call **LCM(5, 7)**, You will get **35**.

Comment: The solution as stated doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    count = 1
    for i in range(count,(maxN*count)+1):
        count = count + 1
    else:
      print(minN*(count-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some simplification. Here's your original code:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    count = 1
    for i in range(count,(maxN*count)+1):
        print(minN*count)
        count = count + 1
```

`count` could be removed from this:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    for i in range(1, maxN+1):
        print(minN*i)
```

Now, you want to print just the last value of this sequence. The last value of `i` will be `maxN`:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    for i in range(1, maxN+1):
        pass
    print(minN * maxN)
```

Or simply:

```
def LCM(minN,maxN):
    print(minN * maxN)
```