# How do I get the function to print out only the final count of the list?

Tags: python

How do I get the function to print out only the final count of the list? I keep getting the count from each loop

```
list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C']

dic = {}
    for item in list:
        dic[item] = list.count(item)
        print (dic)
```

​

```
{'A': 3}
{'A': 3}
{'A': 3, 'B': 1}
{'A': 3, 'B': 1}
{'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print only the last value in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186574/how-do-i-print-only-the-last-value-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

put the print (dic) out of the loop:

```
list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C']

dic = {}
for item in list:
    dic[item] = list.count(item)
print (dic)
```

Comment: sorry just getting back to this now, brilliant thank you. so simple just couldnt see it